# Create new tensor based on indexes from another tensor and allocate with it's values

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, numpy-ndarray

I have a tensor `t` looks like this `[[0, 1, 1.5], [1, 1, 7.3], [2, 0, 2.3]]` and I need to create new tensor `t1` with shape (3, 3, 1) where `t1[t[:, :1], t[:, 1:2]]`(elements from first column used as first coordinate, elements from second column as second coordinate) is allocated with elements from third column of `t`. Like this `t1 = [[[0.0], [1.5], [0.0]], [[0.0], [7.3], [0.0]], [[2.3], [0.0], [0.0]]]`. How can I do it using matrix operations in TensorFlow (or Numpy) without cycles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`tf.sparse_to_dense`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_to_dense) for that:

```
tf.sparse_to_dense(tf.to_int32(t[:, :2]), [3, 3], t[:, 2])[..., None]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
import numpy as np

t = np.asarray([[0,1,1.5],[1,1,7.3],[2,0,2.3]])

t1 = np.zeros([3,3,1])
t1[t[:,0].astype(int), t[:,1].astype(int),0] = t[:,2]
```